# Can I connect a "Player" class from models to a field in UserCreationForm from the Django library

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating an app that allows you to input your name, email, password in a form and it creates a Player with a base integer ELO score, date field, and name and later add a form that creates a Game with 2 Player fields, 2 integer fields for goals scored, and a date field. The app will have 3 main form functionalities: 1) lookup player game history and score 2) add game (I want to add games in a way that they are connected to the Players that are input), and finally register (create a User with a name, password and email login and use the name to create the Player instance that will be bound to the user. I can currently access my admin page and manually choose a user for the Players that I created in the terminal but I am confused how I should create my registration form in a way that the Player is created automatically when the user registers. Hopefully once I see how binding Players to Users works I will be able to figure out how to bind Games to Players

I have tried adding a forms.ModelField(Player) and made the field hidden but I am unsure how to assign the name to the Player.

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Player


class PlayerForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    player = forms.ModelForm(Player, widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'player',
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(PlayerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

my models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    elo = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " = " + str(self.elo)


class Game(models.Model):
    date_played = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    p1goal = models.IntegerField()
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    p2goal = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_played) + " - " + str(self.player1) + " " + str(self.p1goal) + " to " + \
               str(self.p2goal) + str(self.player2)
```

I tried adding user.player = Player(name, elo) with the elo field being 1000 and the name by user.first_name + " " + user.last_name and i tried self.first_name + " " + self.last_name but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(PlayerForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

    new_player = Player(name=user.first_name,
                        elo=1000,
                        date_added=datetime.datetime.now(),
                        user=user)
    if commit:
        user.save()
        new_player.save()
```

Comment: You don't need most of those assignments on `user`, they will be done by the super save call.